# On edit, Country selection working but State name doesn't selected using angular IO

Tags: angular

I have created a module for the country and its state. So on add time, it's working fine but on edit, it doesn't select.

HTML Code

```
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
    <md-card-content class="ml-xs mr-xs" style="width: 100%">
        <md-select placeholder="Country" [formControl]="formCompany.controls['CountryId']" [ngModel]="CompanyEdit.CountryId" #countryId (change)="getStateslist($event.value)">
        <md-option *ngFor="let country of getCountries"   [value]="country.id">{{country.CountryName}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-card-content>
<small *ngIf="formCompany.controls['CountryId'].hasError('required') && formCompany.controls['CountryId'].touched" class="mat-text-warn">Please select country.</small>
</div>

<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
  <md-card-content class="ml-xs mr-xs" style="width: 100%">
    <md-select *ngIf="getStates" placeholder="State" [formControl]="formCompany.controls['StateId']" [ngModel]="CompanyEdit.StateId">
    <md-option *ngFor="let getState of getStates" [value]="getState.id"> {{getState.StateName}} </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-card-content>
<small *ngIf="formCompany.controls['StateId'].hasError('required') && formCompany.controls['StateId'].touched" class="mat-text-warn">Please select state.</small>
</div>
```

// Component File Code

```
this.formCompany = this.fb.group({
    StateId: [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    CountryId: [null,Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
}});
```

On Edit

```
if(this.route.snapshot.params['id']){
      this.services.getStates(0).subscribe(res => {this.getStates = res});   
      this.services.getCompanyById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(res => {this.CompanyEdit = res } );
    }
```

Comment: Make your content presentable, remove horizontal scroll in code. Make the code multi line

Comment: What does *on edit, it doesn't select* mean? :)

Comment: It's working now @AJT_82. I updated Angular.